# How Do I Pass HREF Class To JQUERY Success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to only replace part of the anchor tag of my HTML.  I have it working so that it replaces the entire string, but I only want to replace part of it.  I have several sections with the same class and it's above this particular section of HTML.  It's working, but I want to be able to only replace part of the string.

HTML...

```
<div class="upvote-comment-count">
<a href="{% url 'Suggestions:suggestion_comment_upvotes' pk=reply.id %}" id="upvote-comment-url">{{ reply.total_comment_upvotes }}</a>
</div>
   
<button type="button" class="button6" data-href="{% url 'Suggestions:suggestion_comment_like' reply.id %}">Like</button>
```

AJAX....

```
    $(document).on("click",'.button6',function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $this = $(this);
       $liked = $(this); // the link clicked

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: $this.data("href"),
           dataType: "json",
           csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
           beforeSend: function(xhr) {
           xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ csrf_token }}");
           },
           success: function(response){
           $this.prev().html(response['total_comment_upvotes']); 
           },
        });
        return false;
    });
```

It successfully replaces the total_comment_upvotes in my HTML.  I'm trying to do something more along the lines of...

```
document.getElementById('upvote-comment-url').innerHTML = response['total_upvotes'];
```

I have tried to add an id="upvote-comment-url" to the anchor tag string to reference it but I've tried to also reference it like...

```
$this.prev("upvote-comment-url").html(response['total_comment_upvotes']);
```

But this doesn't work. I've also tried prevAll as well as closest.  I'm using Chrome and I don't see any error messages with some of my attempts but I can't get my anchor tag HREF to work after button6 is pressed.  I have to manually refresh the screen.  I had a similar question earlier and was able to solve it by specifying an ID.  In this case...I can't use a simple document.getElementByID...since there are potentially multiple sections as this is a recurring comment section with likes.  I need to be more specific...with a $this...and a prev or something to that effect.  Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Well after eons of trial and error....I had to add a find parameter to my line of code to get it to select just the  tag line like I was after...

```
$this.prev().find('#upvote-comment-url').html(response['total_comment_upvotes']);
```

This seemed to do the trick.